# Why does dict(enumerate(myset)) return a jumbled up dict, unlike dict(enumerate(list))?

Tags: python, dictionary, set, enumerate

I have been trying to study the simplest of things and would appreciate if someone explains why this behaves the way it does. Code snippet below:

*#Creating dict from set using enumerate:*

```
    myset = {'A','A','B','C'}
    mydict = dict(enumerate(myset))
    print(mydict)
```

*Output:*

```
    {0: 'B', 1: 'C', 2: 'A'}
```

*My Expected Output:*

```
    {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}
```

Whereas, it works fine with lists!

*#Creating dict from list using enumerate:*

```
    li = ["apple","banana","mango"]
    mydict = dict(enumerate(myset))
    print(mydict)
```

*Output:*

```
    {0: 'apple', 1: 'banana', 2: 'mango'}
```

Explanation appreciated!

Comment: The order of elements in a set is unspecified, and CPython deliberately shuffles it to prevent you from depending on consistent ordering.

Comment: @Barmar: Are you thinking of Go maps or something? There's no deliberate shuffling in a CPython set.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I thought I remembered a question where someone ran code like this repeatedly, and got a different order each time.

Comment: @Barmar: You might be thinking of the effects of hash randomization - a few built-in types have hashes that depend on random state initialized at interpreter setup. This is intended to make hash collision attacks more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Sets do not have order, but lists do. That's why when you enumerate the set it doesn't do it in your intended order. More info can be found in the [official documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/set.html)